# What numbering system is used by terminal when outputing to a script

Tags: input, data-structures, terminal

I'm currently learning C programming, and wrote a script similar to one I've written in Python before. My goal is to learn how to pass input to an application and have it process the data I pass it.

The problem I'm having now is the feedback my application is giving me. I wrote a simple application to read keyboard input and give 1 of 3 responses based on what input I give it. The code is as follows:

```
/*Input test.*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


char input;
const int option_a = 1;
const int option_b = 2;


int main()
{

    printf("Lets get started! a for on or b for off?\n");
    while(1)
    {
        input = getchar();
        if(input == option_a)
        {
            printf("We're on.!\n");
        }
        else if(input == option_b)
        {
            printf("Off we go.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Excuse me, but I didn't get that.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Simply option_a is me pressing the 1 key on keyboard, and option_b is key 2. When I press these keys, or any key for that matter, the application will always go to the "else" portion of the decision tree. Saying that, it's clear to me that, and I'll say with a lack of a better term/expression, that my application isn't seeing my input as the decimal number 1 or 2.

From the terminal, what is the structure of the data I'm sending to my application, or simply put, what does my 1or 2 "look" like to my application?

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking input with `getchar()` you are getting an `char` value. But you are comparing it with an integer. Instead of comparing with the integer, you can compare the input with corresponding characters. For example, use

```
const char option_a = '1';
const char option_b = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to find the American Standard Code for information interchange(ASCII) table. 0 = 48, 1 = 49, 2 = 50,...I had the same problem while working with arduino’s serial monitor, and it should all be covered by the same standard.